# JavaScript error: Unexpected anonymous System.register call

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

There is a simple TypeScript project in Visual Studio 2015 with two TypeScript files:

**foo.ts**

```
export class Foo {
    bar(): string {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**app.ts**

```
/// <reference path="foo.ts"/>
import {Foo}  from './foo';
var foo = new Foo();
```

foo.ts is compiled into:

**foo.js**

```
System.register([], function(exports_1) {
    var Foo;
    return {
        setters:[],
        execute: function() {
            Foo = (function () {
                function Foo() {
                }
                Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
                    return "hello";
                };
                return Foo;
            })();
            exports_1("Foo", Foo);
        }
    }
});
```

When I load foo.js in html page, the Google Chrome console shows the error:

**"system.src.js:4935 Uncaught TypeError: Unexpected anonymous System.register"**

Obviously, this is because of the line

```
 System.register([], function(exports_1)
```

Compiler options in tsconfig.json:

```
 {
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system"
  }
}
```

Script download in index.html:

```
<script src="./lib/system.js"></script>
<script src="./app/foo.js"></script>
<script src="./app/app.js"></script>
```

tsc version: 1.9.0-dev.20160322

When I don't import anything and put everything in one app.js file the code works properly, without any errors.
How to overcome the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have figured out what is the problem, I initialized the application in a wrong way.

Initialization should be added in **index.html**, something like this:

```
<script>
    System.config({
          packages: { 'app': { defaultExtension: 'js' } }
    });
    System.import('app/app');
</script>
```

And it was wrong to include **foo.js** and **app.j**s in this way:

```
<script src="./app/foo.js"></script>
<script src="./app/app.js"></script>
```